# Generate graphical schema representation from CREATE TABLE SQL

Tags: sql, macos, data-modeling, erd

I have a .sql file containing many CREATE TABLE statements. There's no referential specification (MyISAM stuff) but I would enjoy to create different table boxes, and then compose the table relationships by hand. I am using a mac. Is there a free program to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.1.html) can reverse-engineer a diagram from an SQL script that contains a set of `CREATE TABLE` statements.

Use the menu: **File > Import > Reverse Engineer MySQL Create Script...**

Answer (score 2):

Go to [SchemaBank](http://schemabank.com), open a free account, import your sql file and start editing. Nothing to install at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems to have disappeared from the web :(